# Can't create a new rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I got everything to work. When I first tried:

rails new myApp

it created the app and then I ran:

rails server

that worked fine too with localhost:3000

but then I tried making another app, which was created but gave me a message stating that server is already running and then it exited. Therefore, my locahost wasn't working anymrore.

Then I did some fooling around and I think I just made it worse!!

here is where I am at now:

```html
~$ rails new blog
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/lib/rails_generator/generators/applications/app/app_generator.rb:7: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
      exists  
      exists  app/controllers
      exists  app/helpers
      exists  app/models
      exists  app/views/layouts
      exists  config/environments
      exists  config/initializers
      exists  config/locales
      exists  db
      exists  doc
      exists  lib
      exists  lib/tasks
      exists  log
      exists  public/images
      exists  public/javascripts
      exists  public/stylesheets
      exists  script/performance
      exists  test/fixtures
      exists  test/functional
      exists  test/integration
      exists  test/performance
      exists  test/unit
      exists  vendor
      exists  vendor/plugins
      exists  tmp/sessions
      exists  tmp/sockets
      exists  tmp/cache
      exists  tmp/pids
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  README
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
   identical  config/database.yml
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
   identical  db/seeds.rb
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
   identical  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
overwrite config/initializers/session_store.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]
```

WHAT DO I DO!????

ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
Rails 2.3.14
rvm 1.26.10 (latest)

Please advise.

Thanks guys!

T

Answer (score 0):

You must have closed your terminal while the rails server was still running. In the future, to exit the server hold **Control** + **C**.
 Since you already closed it you'll need to manually terminate the server. In your bash run `ps aux | grep rails`

you see this kind of output:

```
yourname   2675   0.0  0.4  2531340  69224 s000  S+   11:06PM   0:02.05 /Users/youname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby bin/rails s
```

To "kill" the server  run `kill -9 2675`.  The last four numbers must match the four digits after your name.

Comment: Unfortunately i still get the same problem :(

Comment: what directory are you currently in? can you run `pwd` and show me the output

Comment: I am running in my home directy. /home/T. but when I type rails new blog it list this long stuff as pasted above... overwrite config/initializers/session_store.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]  I always get this, and my "blog" doesn't get created.

Comment: When I tried rails new myApp i didnt get that long list it actually created my myApp and then I cd myApp and ran rails server and it worked great! but now I did something (dont remember, so some sort of installation) and I now get what you see in my first post :(

Comment: im not following anymore...Do you still have an issue or are you able to run the server and connect to localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

Run this command, it will terminate all the running rails servers.

```
killall -9 ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

> ps ax | grep rails

This will show you the processes running having to do with Rails. The first number shown is the process ID. Look for the process that is running the Rails server, grab it's process ID, and type:

> kill -9 processID

This will kill the Rails server that's running.